# Unable to install Swagger Php

Tags: swagger, swagger-php

I am trying to install Swagger php for ubuntu from http://blog.nbostech.com/2016/01/integrating-swagger-ui-for-php-application/

In that link they ask me to run the following command - "php composer.phar require zircote/swagger-php".

When i give, "php composer.phar require zircote/swagger-php" in my terminal it says "Could not open input file: composer.phar". Due to this error i am unable to proceed swagger-php installation from above link.

I am in need of Support.

Comment: First you need to  install composer from the following link to exicute php composer.phar

https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 0):

1) Install composer for your php.
2) Use meantioned command if composer was installed locally.
3) Use "composer require zircote/swagger-php" if composer is used globally.

4) Consult composer documenation for proper syntax if you use something different then Linux/MacOS.

**Above commands have to be executed inside php project, which will be annotated**

Answer (score 0):

To install `zircote/swagger-php` first you need to have `php` installed in your system correctly (obviously), so to verify that run following command in terminal

```
php -v
```

If you don't have `php` installed, run this,

```
sudo apt install php
```

Then to [download composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) run these set of commands

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Then make [composer run globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally%60). This way you can run `composer` from any directory within your system and there's no need to run `php composer.phar`

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then finally, navigate to your project folder and simply do

```
composer require zircote/swagger-php
```